# What does `< <` do (note the space between the two `<` symbols)?

Tags: linux, io-redirection

What exactly does `< <` do in the following context?

After opening up gdb with a binary, `b1`, things are run by giving the command `r < <(./b2)` where `b2` is a second binary.

I am a bit confused as to what the space between the two `<` symbols is doing there. If I had to guess, I would say that the output of `b2` is getting fed to the input of `b1`. But then why not just do `<` or `<<`?

Comment: The `<(./b2)` is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). I don't understand it well enough to know why you'd want it in conjunction with the regular `<` redirection.

Comment: It's an obfuscated way of doing `./b2 | ./b1`.  The main reason for doing it is that gdb's `run` command can't really handle `|` properly.

Comment: Hi @ChrisDodd. Thank you for answering as the question I was marked a duplicate of didn't really get at what I was asking. Can you elaborate any more as to why gdb can't handle piping well?

Comment: If you did `run ./b2 | ./b1` it would make `./b2` an argument to your program rather than running it on its own.  It also doesn't know which of the subprocesses of the pipeline created to attach to -- depending on what the shell does, it might get either.

Comment: As for your final question of "why not just do <" -- because that would read from the exec image in the file rather than running it.